# "Currying" a function in emacs lisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

I have many handy functions which operate on the current word or region, and due to laziness etc. I've build them out of a template...

For example

```
(defun lower-camelcase-at-point-or-region ()
  "lowerCamelCaseTheCurrent dashed or snake_case word or any words in text selection."
  (interactive)
  (let (pos1 pos2 meat)
    (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
        (setq pos1 (region-beginning)
              pos2 (region-end))
      (setq pos1 (car (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
            pos2 (cdr (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))))
    (setq meat (s-lower-camel-case (buffer-substring-no-properties pos1 pos2)))
    (delete-region pos1 pos2)
    (insert  meat)    
    )
  )
```

Effectively this is all boiler plate, except for this line...

```
(setq meat (s-lower-camel-case (buffer-substring-no-properties pos1 pos2)))
```

Where I call `s-lower-camel-case` on the buffer substring. I want to reuse the at point or region stuff, but without duplicating it everywhere, (because that's stupid, and a headache to maintain.)

So what I really want to know is, can I curry functions in Emacs Lisp?

When I tried this...

```
(defun do-stuff-on-point-or-region ()
  "Do stuff."
  (interactive)
  (operate-on-point-or-region 's-lower-camel-case)
)
```

With `operate-on-point-or-region` defined as...:

```
(defun operate-on-point-or-region (fn)
  "Pick the substring at point, or region 
   and replace it with the output of fn"
  (let (pos1 pos2 meat)
    (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
        (setq pos1 (region-beginning)
              pos2 (region-end))
      (setq pos1 (car (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
            pos2 (cdr (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))))
    (setq meat (fn (buffer-substring-no-properties pos1 pos2)))
    (delete-region pos1 pos2)
    (insert  meat)    
    )
)
```

I get : `Symbol's function definition is void: fn`

Am I foolishly assuming currying is possible in Emacs Lisp!? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, emacs-lisp is, kinda, sorta, a 2-lisp, so the following is invalid:

```
(defun foo (fn)
  (fn 3)) ;; DOES NOT WORK!
```

Instead, you have to do the following:

```
(defun foo (fn)
  (funcall fn 3))
```

So if you replace `(setq meat (fn` with `(setq meat (funcall fn` the code ought to work.

Answer (score 8):

I wish to add that in Emacs lisp currying is not possible -- function application is not currying, because it does not follow the curry's formula.

Currying means to apply a function to partial arguments, and return another function. This is not possible in Elisp, due to the dynamic scope.

EDIT: UPDATE

Now emacs-gnu has closures.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that what I was trying to do is currying?

Comment: @Slomojo: Yes, what you are trying to do is to use higher-order functions.

Comment: Actually, with judicious use of lexical-let, it's eminently possible to curry functions in emacs-lisp. But it's quite possible you don't actually want to.

Comment: As it turns out, I think what I wanted to do would be better termed as composition, since I wasn't supplying the function with arguments (proper currying), merely providing the function to be called as an alias within the body of the other function.

Comment: To make a curry, you need a `closure`. Emacs does not have closures (I think that there is an auxiliary library that wants to simulate common lisp, but I never used it, sorry). Instead, I use scheme. Read my detailed post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552597/currying-a-function-n-times-in-scheme/13568216#13568216

Comment: @Alinsoar - so what I wanted to do wasn't currying anyway - which is a bit more complex. Emacs, doesn't have the lexical scoping that scheme does, however, with macros and lexical-let it can simulate a `closure` - I've also just read that this stuff is in the works (properly, ie. not simulated.), but that may be Emacs25 or beyond. (this is according to the lexical scope discussion on EmacsWiki and notes in Emacs News, in the environment itself.) - I'll have a hunt in `cl` (the library that provides a lot of common lisp) - Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes. Emacs will have closures in the near future installed. They were planned very long time ago. In fact , many features are planned / worked on, and still pending for installation. They install them in order of priorities. I also am waiting for my code to be installed, but I still do not know when they install it, as they said, because that depends on the free time of Stefan Monnier.

Comment: Emacs has native support for lexical scoping (and hence closures) since version 24.1.

Comment: Consider changing the title of the post, perhaps to something about higher-order functions or using function-valued arguments. The discussion about clarifying wrt currying might still help some people, but for those searching, the title can mislead.

Comment: Feel free to change it as you consider better, but please do not mutilate the name, otherwise I will revert the change.